# Change ruby variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my jquery to obtain a ID in a Dropdown.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#installationsDropDown1 li a').on('click', function(){
            Id = $(this).html();
        });
    });

</script>

    <div class="ibox-content graph">
      <%= high_chart('main-graph', @highcharts[Id]) %>
    </div>
```

How can I pass dynamic the variable Id to the ruby code in view?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just pass variables from your javascript code to your ruby code.

If I understood correctly, you have two choices:

Make an AJAX call when the user clicks on your link. This call will render your "high_chart" method in your div. So you'll have to create an action, and a js.erb view. Something like :

```
$("ibox-content.graph").html("<%= high_chart('main-graph', @highchart) %>");
```

Your @highchart variable will be instantiated in your controller using the parameter that you will send with your AJAX call (your ID for instance).

Another method is to preload all your charts in ruby when the page is loaded. Then you will manage in JS the one you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in an erb view on the server, there is no point in using jQuery. Leave the jQuery on the client side and let the controller handle the logic on your rails server.

If this is on the client side, then the erb <% %> tags will not work as those are rendered by the server.